# Unicode error while opening a tar.gz file in python 3

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, tar, farsi

I have a 800MB tar.gz in Farsi/Persian and I'm trying to open it into a dataframe and I use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Arshasb_7k.tar.gz', compression='gzip', header=0, sep=' ', quotechar='"', 
error_bad_lines=False)
df = df.drop(0)
df.rename(columns={0: "file_name", 1: "text"}, inplace=True)
df.head()
```

and I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 4096: invalid start byte

I tried everything I found in here and it still doesn't work. Help me please.

Comment: I don't think `pd.read_csv` can handle gzipped tar files. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#quoting-compression-and-file-format) mention gzip, but not tar. You probably need to unpack the archive with the std-lib `tarfile` module yourself and pass the extracted CSV to Pandas.